# Rudimentary bitwise (I think) OR example?

Tags: c, if-statement, bit-manipulation

So I want an if statement to be like: `if (foo == ("bar" | "barbar"))`.  I think this is the bitwise OR operator, but I'm not sure.  Anyways, this doesn't work.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Care to add language you want this construct to work?

Comment: Which language are you talking about? And what is your definition of bitwise OR regarding strings?

Comment: C.  Sorry, I thought that might be too much information.

Comment: What is `foo`? The statement as written can almost never be useful, ever.

Comment: it's the bitwise or operator,as you mentioned. And it does not works with non-integer types or unrelated to int. In fact, Are you looking for an alternative to if(foo == "baa" || foo == "barbar")? note: you are comparing points addresses in this statement, if you want to compare the values, you need to use strcmp() instead of.

Answer (score 2):

As @cnicutar stated, the bitwise OR operator `|` is not defined for string literals.

It seems to me that you're trying to execute code if foo is equal to either "bar" or "barbar". This *would* (note that this WILL NOT work) look like this (utilizing the standard, boolean OR operator, `||`):

```
if ((foo == "bar") || (foo == "barbar"))
```

This won't work (it will compile, but probably not do what you intended) because "bar" and "barbar" (and I guess foo, too) are character pointers, and this if statement would compare the ADDRESSES of these strings. What you would do is this:

```
if ((strcmp(foo, "bar") == 0) || (strcmp(foo, "barbar") == 0))
```

Note that you'll have to check whether the result of strcmp() is 0, as this denotes equality.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyways, this doesn't work. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

The bitwise or operator isn't defined for string literals, so it makes no sense to use it in that context.

Comment: Okay, so how could I go about doing this?

Comment: @JackStone Doing what exactly. It' unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Meaning comparing two values without having to write more than one comparison.  So instead of writing `if (foo == "bar" || foo == "barbar")`, I could write `if (foo == "bar" || "barbar")` or something along those lines.

Comment: @JackStone You don't. You *need* to use more than one comparison. Also, you don't want to compare strings with `==`.

Comment: @cnicutar It certainly is defined. It takes the bitwise or of the pointers to the string literals.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare strings you need to use `strcmp()` ([manpage](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html)):

```
if (strcmp(foo, "bar") == 0 ||
    strcmp(foo, "barber") == 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bit-wise OR operator does an OR operation on the individual bits in the values being ORed.

Examples:
    0b10111001
|  0b01101101
==   0b11111101

```
uint8_t a = 0xF0;
uint8_t b = 0x0F;
uint8_t c = a | b; // This is 0xFF
```

In the case of literals, the value being operated on by the OR operator are their addresses and thus won't work how your code seems to intend.

As was stated in previous answers, you should use the `strcmp` or `strncmp` functions from the `string.h` library to compare strings.